# If $f$ is Darboux Integrable on $[a,b]$ and function $g$ disagrees with $f$ at a finite number of points on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

The aim of this proof is to demonstrate the following claim:

> If $f$ is Darboux Integrable (DI) on $[a,b]$ and function $g$ disagrees with $f$ at a finite number of points on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$

This proof is broken up into three sections.

I think sections 2 and 3 are straightforward consequences of section 1. I have some doubts about my section 1, though...in particular, my handling of the partition $S$.

---

*Section 1*

> Let $f$ be DI on $[a,b]$. If $g$ is a function such that $g(a) \neq f(a)$ and for all $x \in (a,b]: g(x)=f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$

We will need the following two lemmas:

$*_1$ If $f$ is a Darboux Integrable (DI) function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ disagrees with $f$ at a finite number of points, then $g$ is DI on $[a,b]$. The proof of this lemma can be found here: [If $f$ is a Darboux Integrable (DI) function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ disagrees with $f$ at a finite number of points, then $g$ is DI on $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494903/if-f-is-a-darboux-integrable-di-function-on-a-b-and-g-disagrees-with)

$*_2$ Suppose $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$. Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Let $Q$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $P \subseteq Q$. Then the upper sums of $f$ on $[a,b]$ have the following properties:$U(f,Q) \leq U(f,P)$.

To show that $\int_a^b f= \int_a^b g$, we will demonstrate that, given the assumptions, $\int_a^b f \gt \int_a^b g$ and $\int_a^b f \lt \int_a^b g$ both lead to contradictions.

Without loss of generality, suppose the $g(a) \gt f(a)$. This assumption **will be maintained throughout the entirety of this first section's proof** (a similarly structured argument can be used if $g(a) \lt f(a)$).

First, assume that $\int_a^b f \gt \int_a^b g$. By $*_1$, we know that if $\int_a^b f \gt \int_a^b g$, there must be a partition $Q$ of $[a,b]$ such that for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]: L(f,Q) \geq L(g,P)+ \eta$ for some $\eta \gt 0 \quad (\dagger_1)$. This is because our assumptions force us to conclude that $\displaystyle \sup_P L(f,P) \gt \sup_P L(g,P)$. Therefore, if we can find a partition $P$ that contradicts this statement, we must have $ \int_a^b f \not \gt \int_a^b g$.

Let $Q=\{a=t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_{n-1},t_n=b\}$ be the partition that satisfies $\dagger_1$. Let $L(f,Q)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n m_i^f(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$, where $m_i^f$ is the infimum of $f$'s image for a given subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. Suppose we let $Q=P$. Then we can write $L(g,P)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n m_i^g[t_i-t_{i-1}]$, where $m_i^g$ is the infimum of $g$'s image for a given subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. By assumption, $f$ certainly agrees with $g$ in every subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ where $i\gt 1$. This means that for $i \gt 1$, we have that $m_i^f=m_i^g$.

Consider the interval $[t_0,t_1]$. On this interval, there are two possibilities: $m_1^f=f(a)$ or $m_1^f \lt f(a)$...we can immediately rule out $m_1^f \gt f(a)$. If $m_1^f \lt f(a)$, because the point $a$ is the only location of disagreement between $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) \lt g(a)$, it is clear that $m_1^g=m_1^f$. In this case, we then must have that $L(f,Q)=L(g,P)$, which shows that $L(g,P)+\eta \gt L(f,Q)$, a contradiction.

So suppose $m_1^f=f(a)$. Either there is an $x \in (t_0,t_1]$ such that $f(x)=m_1^f$ or for all $x \in (t_0,t_1]: f(x) \gt m_1^f$. In the former case, because $g(a) \gt f(a)$, we must have that $m_1^g=m_1^f$. In the latter case, even though no value equals $m_1^f$, it is still possible that the infimum of $f$'s range on $(t_0,t_1]$ is $m_1^f$. If this occurs, then, clearly, $m_1^g=m_1^f$. If this does not occur, then $f(a)$ must be the only minimum point of $f$ on $[t_0,t_1]$, and because $g(a) \gt f(a)$, we would have that $m_1^g \gt m_1^f$. Regardless, across all cases, we have that $m_1^g \geq m_1^f$, which means that $L(f,Q) \leq L(g,P)$. Once again, this implies that $L(g,P)+\eta \gt L(f,Q)$, a contradiction. So we have that $ \int_a^b f \not \gt \int_a^b g$.

Next, still assuming that $g(a) \gt f(a)$, suppose $\int_a^b f \lt \int_a^b g$. Because of $*_1$, this implies that $\displaystyle \inf_P U(f,P) \lt \inf_P U(g,P)$. Equivalently, this means that there is a partition $Q$ of $[a,b]$ such that for any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ we have $U(f,Q)+\eta \leq U(g,P)$ for some $\eta \gt 0 \quad (\dagger_2)$. If we can show that there is a partition $P$  of $[a,b]$ such that $U(g,P)  \lt U(f,Q)+\eta$, we will have a contradiction, which means that $\int_a^b f \not \lt \int_a^b g$.

Let $Q=\{t_0=a,t_1,\cdots, t_{n-1},t_n=b\}$ be the partition that satisfies $\dagger_2$. Let $U(f,Q)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n M_i^f[t_{i}-t_{i-1}]$, where $M_i^f$ is the supremum of $f$'s image for a given subinterval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$. Consider the partition $S$ of $[a,b]$ defined as $S=\{s_0,s_1,s_2\cdots,s_{n}, s_{n+1}\}$ where $s_0=t_0=a, s_2=t_1, \cdots, s_{n}=t_{n-1}, s_{n+1}=t_n=b$ and $s_1 \in (t_0,t_1)$. Then we can write $U(g,S)$ as $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}N_j^g[s_{j}-s_{j-1}]$, where $N_j^g$ is the supremum of $g$'s image for a given subinterval $[s_{j-1},s_{j}]$. Further, let us also consider $U(f,S)$, which we will write as $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n+1}N_j^f[s_j-s_{j-1}]$, where $N_j^f$ is the supremum of $f$'s image for a given subinterval $[s_{j-1},s_{j}]$.

Because $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b]$, it is straightforward to see that $U(g,S)-U(f,S)=[N_1^g-N_1^f][s_1-a]$. Either $N_1^g=g(a)$ or $N_1^g \gt g(a)$ ($N_1^g \lt g(a)$ can be ruled out immediately). If $N_1^g \gt g(a)$, then there must be some other element $x \in (a,s_1]$ such that $g(a) \lt g(x) \leq N_1^g$...but for such an $x$, we know that $f(x)=g(x)$, in which case, $N_1^g$ is determined by the same values that determine $N_1^f$. i.e. $N_1^g=N_1^f \quad \dagger_3$. Next, by our second lemma $*_2$, we know that $U(f,S) \leq U(f,Q)$. By $\dagger_3$, we would then have that $U(g,S)-U(f,S)=0$. But this would mean that $U(g,S)=U(f,S) \leq U(f,Q) \lt U(f,Q)+\eta$, our desired contradiction.

So suppose instead that $N_1^g=g(a)$. Then we have that $U(g,S)-U(f,S)=[g(a)-N_1^f][s_1-a]$. Because $[a,s_1] \subset [a,t_1]$, it should be clear that the infimum $m_1^f$ of $f$'s image on the interval $[a,t_1]$ satisfies the following property: $m_1^f \leq N_1^f$. This means that $[g(a)-N_1^f][s_1-a] \leq [g(a)-m_1^f][s_1-a]$. Because $g(a) \gt f(a)$, we necessarily have that $g(a) \gt m_1^f$, which means that $g(a)-m_1^f \neq 0$. We can then solve for $s_1$ using the following chain of inequalities: $[g(a)-m_1^f][s_1-a] \lt \eta \implies s_1 \lt \frac{\eta}{g(a)-m_1^f}+a$. If this condition is satisfied, we then have that $U(g,S)-U(f,S) \lt \eta$, which means that $U(g,S) \lt U(f,S)+\eta$. By our second lemma $*_2$, this means that $U(g,S) \lt U(f,Q)+\eta$, our desired contradiction. Thus, we can conclude that $ \int_a^b f \not \lt \int_a^b g$.

Combining this with our previous result, we must have that $\int_a^b f= \int_a^b g$. For the case of $g(a) \lt f(a)$, we simply flip around the style of arguments...so we can generalize to the condition of $g(a)\neq f(a)$. Further, it should be apparent that this proof has a logical symmetry to it, such that the following claim is also true:

> Let $f$ be DI on $[a,b]$. If $g$ is a function such that $g(b) \neq f(b)$ and for all $x \in [a,b): g(x)=f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$

---

*Section 2*

> Let $f$ be DI on $[a,b]$. If $g$ is a function such that $g(a) \neq f(a)$, $g(b) \neq f(b)$, and for all $x \in (a,b): g(x)=f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$.

To prove this, we will make use of the following lemma:

$*_3$ Let $a \lt c \lt b$. If $f$ is DI on $[a,c]$ and on $[b,c]$, then $\int_a^b f= \int_a^c f+\int_c^b f$.

Choose any $c \in (a,b)$ and consider the intervals $[a,c]$ and $[c,b]$. Apply our results from *Section 1* to each subinterval. We then have that $\int_a^c f=\int_a^c g$ and $\int_c^b f=\int_c^b g \quad \dagger_4$. An application of $*_3$ provides us with: $\int_a^b g=\int_a^c g+\int_c^b g$ and $\int_a^b f= \int_a^c f+\int_c^b f$. Combining this with $\dagger_4$ then gives us:

$$\int_a^b g=\int_a^c g + \int_c^b g = \int_a^c f+\int_c^b f = \int_a^b f \implies \int_a^b g= \int_a^b f$$, as desired.

---

*Section 3*

We can use our results from *Section 1* and *Section 2* to prove the final claim:

> If $f$ is Darboux Integrable (DI) on $[a,b]$ and function $g$ disagrees with $f$ at a finite number of points on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$

Let the points of disagreement between $f$ and $g$ be denoted by: $x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_n$...i.e. for each $i \in \{0,1,\cdots n\}$, we have that $f(x_i) \neq g(x_i)$, where all such $x_i \in [a,b]$. For all other points $z$, we have that $f(z)=g(z)$. There are three general categories of disagreement structure:

1. $x_0=a$ and for all other $i \in \{1,2, \cdots, n\}: x_i \in (a,b)$
2. $x_0=a$ and $x_n=b$ for all other $i \in \{1,2, \cdots, n-1\}: x_i \in (a,b)$
3. For all $i \in \{0,1, \cdots, n\}: x_i \in (a,b)$

The arguments used to prove the desired claim for each category are highly similar, so we will only focus on proving the first category.

First, we subdivide the interval $[a,b]$ in the following way: $[x_0,x_1]=[a,x_1]$, $[x_1,x_2], \cdots, [x_{n-1},x_n], [x_n,b]$. This amounts to $n+1$ subintervals. For $[a,x_1]$, by assumption, we have that $f(a) \neq g(a)$ and $f(x_1)\neq g(x_1)$. For all other $z \in (a,x_1)$, we have that $f(z)=g(z)$. This subinterval then qualifies for an application of our result from *Section 2*: $\int_a^{x_1} g = \int_a^{x_1} f$. A similar argument can be applied to each subinterval of the form $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ for all $i \in \{1,\cdots, n\}$, which gives us $\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} g = \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} f$.

For the final interval $[x_n,b]$, we observe that $f(x_n) \neq g(x_n)$ and for all $z \in (x_n,b]: g(x)=f(x)$. We can therefore apply our result from *Section 1*, giving us: $\int_{x_n}^b g= \int_{x_n}^b f$. It is straightforward to see that our third lemma $*_3$ from *Section 2* can be generalized to:

$*_4$ Let $a \lt y_1 \lt y_2 \lt \cdots \lt y_n \lt b$. If $f$ is DI on the subintervals $[a,y_1], [y_1,y_2], \cdots , [y_{n-1},y_n],$ and $[y_n,b]$, then $\int_a^b f= \int_a^{y_1} f+\int_{y_1}^{y_2} f+\cdots + \int_{y_{n-1}}^{y_n} f+ \int_{y_n}^b f$

Applying $*_4$, we can make the following argument:

$$\int_a^b g = \int_a^{x_1}g+\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g + \cdots + \int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n}g+\int_{x_n}^bg=\int_a^{x_1}f+\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f + \cdots + \int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_n}f+\int_{x_n}^b f=\int_a^b f \implies \int_a^b g = \int_a^b f$$, as desired. $\quad \square$

Comment: What is the question?  Is it that you want someone to proof-read your work?  Is there some point of the argument that you doubt?

Comment: @GEdgar: I assume that's what OP wants, given the `solution-verification` tag, but it would have been nice to be explicit. :-)

Comment: @GEdgar I will be more explicit in the opening section. I think sections 2 and 3 are straightforward consequences of section 1. I had some doubts about my section 1, though...in particular, my handling of the partition $S$.

Comment: @BrianTung For my own future reference, if I simply want my submitted proof to be 'verified', should I explicitly state in the opening section: "Could someone please verify the correctness of my proof?". Alternatively, if I am confident in my proof, and simply want to post it to the math stack exchange forum in order to *add* to the collection of correct math statements that this forum has 'on record', is there a different tag that you would recommend? Or is it better to first 'ask the the question'  using the appropriate tag (e.g. 'calculus') and then provide my proof as a posted answer?

Comment: It is sufficient to do the proof for the case where $f,g$ differ at a single point.